# C++ STL Containers With Pointers: A few questions

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, subclass

Let's say you have a type `T` and subtypes `TSub1`, `TSub2` etc.

Several of these subtypes are initialised with `new TSub(...)`. The resulting pointers are then stored as elements in:

```
list<T*> tsList;
```

The same pointers are also used as keys in:

```
map<T*,V> tsMap;
```

Now consider an iteration over `tsList`, with iterator variable `tIter`.

Here are my questions:

> 1. Will **`tsMap[*tIter]`** and **`tsMap.find(*tIter)`** both successfully
>      find the correct associated value?
> 2. Will **`delete *tIter`** successfully free the full memory block
>      allocated for the relevant **`TSub`** even though STL sees the type as
>      **`T`**?
> 3. Assume there is a defined method **`T::foo()`** and override **`TSub::foo()`**.
>
>    Will **`(*tIter)->foo()`** call **`T::foo()`** or **`TSub::foo()`** ?

The context is: each `TSub` is desired to be instantiated in singleton fashion, yet be stored in a manner allowing iterative consideration as the supertype, with methods overridden in the subclass being called.

I'd be very grateful for an informed explanation. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Would be easier if you could post some code / demo code to explain what your question.

Comment: My question's perfectly clear, Gob00st. An experienced C++ programmer will be able to give me an answer.

Comment: @KomodoDave As you refer to a "common virtual avoidance trick" it would still be nice to see some code. Do you mean CRTP (this abbreviation would be more understandable to an "experienced C++ programmer")?

Comment: @Christian - Yes I mean CRTP, however I've edited out that info since I realise it won't be possible to create a `list<T*>` if you have `T<TSub1>`, `T<TSub2>` etc, hence `virtual` is a necessity. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will tsMap[*tIter] and tsMap.find(*tIter) both successfully find the
>   correct associated value?

Yes, but tsMap[*tIter] will create a default value if it doesn't find the key.

> Will delete *tIter successfully free the full memory block allocated
>   for the relevant TSub even though STL sees the type as T?

If and only if the destructor of T is virtual

> Assume there is a defined method T::foo() and override TSub::foo().
>
> Will (*tIter)->foo() call T::foo() or TSub::foo() ?

It will call T::foo if T::foo is not virtual. Otherwise it will call TSub::foo()

Comment: A perfect and pleasing answer, thank you very much indeed Armen :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at [Pointer Container Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) from boost.

In addition, I'd suggest that

> Will tsMap[*tIter] and tsMap.find(*tIter) both successfully find the correct associated value?

depends on the definition of successfully. If pointer identity is key identity, yes. If you need to compare pointee objects instead, you need to supply a comparer function object (*callable type in c++0x speak*).

Rather inefficient PoC: (see http://ideone.com/TpgLw)

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
    static bool indirectLess(const T* a, const T* b)
{
    if (a==b) 
        return false;
    if (!a)
        return true;
    if (!b)
        return false;
    return std::less<T>()(*a, *b);
}

typedef int T;
typedef int V;

int main()
{
    typedef bool (*cmp_t)(const T*, const T*);

    std::map<T*,V,cmp_t> tsMap(&indirectLess<T>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, sehe. In my case, I don't need to compare the objects pointed to or I would have said so; my mention of singleton should have made this clear. I'm also not keen on using Boost, I prefer vanilla C++.